# how to strip off left of a specific char and print the rest

Tags: c++

I am try to print a char element but only print off from a specific char on. 
e.g.

```
char* str[265];
str[0] = "hello";
str[1] = "world";
str[2] = "go-to";
str[3] = "//foo.com/moreInfo/contact";
```

But on str[3] i want it to equal contact;  can this be done? 
so save the word after the last "/".

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there any method or combination of methods you could use from `std::string`?

Comment: Usually I look at the C language library to find methods I could use.  For C-Style strings, this looks promising: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr

Comment: This function looks useful: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use C strings in your C++ code, even though C++ `std::string` offers more flexibility, you could use [`strrchr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/strrchr.html) to locate the last slash in `str[3]`, like this:

```
char *tmp = strrchr(str[3], '/');
if (tmp) {
    str[3] = tmp+1;
}
```

You need to `#include <cstring>` for this to compile.

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/pe64aK)